# saving and updating values using firebase of my voting app(android studio)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have been trying to update values of my app but it seems i am missing something.
so i have created an voting app where users can vote but every time i click back button value goes back to zero.using this

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView ( R.layout.activity_second_app );

    A10 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA10 );



  public void A10clicked (View v){
    String A10count =A10.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    int count =Integer.parseInt ( A10count );
    count++;
    A10.setText ( String.valueOf ( count ) );
}
```

and what i want in my app is when users vote value must remain same and lets say for tomorrow values should come to zero mean i want to update that values from firebase.

note- i have 10 textview in each 10 activity field and i am so confused to what to do i tried solutions but its been 5 days i couldnt do anything.

/// activity.java file

```
public class second_app extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView A10;
TextView A11;
TextView A12;
TextView A13;
TextView A14;
TextView A15;
TextView A16;
TextView A17;
TextView A18;
TextView A19;

Button Abtn10;
Button Abtn11;
Button Abtn12;
Button Abtn13;
Button Abtn14;
Button Abtn15;
Button Abtn16;
Button Abtn17;
Button Abtn18;
Button Abtn19;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView ( R.layout.activity_second_app );

    A10 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA10 );

    A11 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA11 );

    A12 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA12 );

    A13 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA13 );

    A14 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA14 );

    A15 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA15);

    A16 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA16 );

    A17 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA17 );

    A18 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA18 );

    A19 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA19 );

    Abtn10 = findViewById ( R.id.btnA10 );

    Abtn11 = findViewById ( R.id.btnA11 );

    Abtn12 = findViewById ( R.id.btnA12 );

    Abtn13 = findViewById ( R.id.btnA13 );

    Abtn14 = findViewById ( R.id.btnA14 );

    Abtn15 = findViewById ( R.id.btnA15 );

    Abtn16 = findViewById ( R.id.btnA16 );

    Abtn17 = findViewById ( R.id.btnA17 );

    Abtn18 = findViewById ( R.id.btnA18 );

    Abtn19 = findViewById ( R.id.btnA19 );





}


public void A10clicked (View v){
    String A10count =A10.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    int count =Integer.parseInt ( A10count );
    count++;
    A10.setText ( String.valueOf ( count ) );
}

public void A11clicked (View v){
    String A11count =A11.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    int count =Integer.parseInt ( A11count );
    count++;
    A11.setText ( String.valueOf ( count ) );
}

public void A12clicked (View v){
    String A12count =A12.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    int count =Integer.parseInt ( A12count );
    count++;
    A12.setText ( String.valueOf ( count ) );
}

public void A13clicked (View v){
    String A13count =A13.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    int count =Integer.parseInt ( A13count );
    count++;
    A13.setText ( String.valueOf ( count ) );
}

public void A14clicked (View v){
    String A14count =A14.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    int count =Integer.parseInt ( A14count );
    count++;
    A14.setText ( String.valueOf ( count ) );
}

public void A15clicked (View v){
    String A15count =A15.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    int count =Integer.parseInt ( A15count );
    count++;
    A15.setText ( String.valueOf ( count ) );
}

public void A16clicked (View v){
    String A16count =A16.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    int count =Integer.parseInt ( A16count );
    count++;
    A16.setText ( String.valueOf ( count ) );
}

public void A17clicked (View v){
    String A17count =A17.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    int count =Integer.parseInt ( A17count );
    count++;
    A17.setText ( String.valueOf ( count ) );
}

public void A18clicked (View v){
    String A18count =A18.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    int count =Integer.parseInt ( A18count );
    count++;
    A18.setText ( String.valueOf ( count ) );
}


public void A19clicked (View v){
    String A19count =A19.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    int count =Integer.parseInt ( A19count );
    count++;
    A19.setText ( String.valueOf ( count ) );
}
```

}

//// xml file

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".second_app">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvA10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_border"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnA10"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:onClick="A10clicked"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="133dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:text="10"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvA11"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_border"

        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnA11"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:onClick="A11clicked"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="133dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
        android:text="11"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvA12"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_border"

        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="510dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnA12"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:onClick="A12clicked"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="133dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="610dp"
        android:text="12"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvA13"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_border"

        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="730dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnA13"
        android:onClick="A13clicked"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="13"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="133dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="830dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvA14"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_border"

        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="950dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnA14"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="A14clicked"
        android:text="14"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="133dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1050dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvA15"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_border"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1170dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnA15"
        android:onClick="A15clicked"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="15"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="133dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1260dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvA16"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_border"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1370dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnA16"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="16"
        android:onClick="A16clicked"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="133dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1470dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvA17"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_border"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1590dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnA17"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="17"
        android:onClick="A17clicked"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="133dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1700dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvA18"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_border"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1810dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnA18"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="18"
        android:onClick="A18clicked"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="133dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1920dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvA19"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2050dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnA19"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="19"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:onClick="A19clicked"
        android:layout_marginLeft="133dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2160dp"/>





</RelativeLayout>
```

i am willing to hear anything from you. this project is for my personal intrest as i have worked on it without any coding knowledge.
thank you so much guys.
database structure is null as i dont have any specific idea what should i be doing hence i left it null.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the vote on a single device. And when the user opens it the next time the previous vote is automatically loaded. This you can do using saved instances. You can save the the instance of the activity as soon as user backpresses i.e closes the app. And if user opens the activity again then you can reload data.
For example if you want to save the value in text field A10 as soon as the user backpresses then you can do like this.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()).edit().putString("value", A10.getString()).apply();
     super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
}
```

Later if user opens the app again then you can retrieve previous value using

```
Context context=this.getApplicationContext();
SharedPreferences settings=context.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCES", 0);
String value=settings.getString("value", "");
```

Comment: i tried and activity does not open. can you tell me where to put above mentioned code meaning below which lines. i am so confused

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView A10;
 
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        A10 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA10 );
        update();
      @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    

PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()).edit().putString("value", A10.getString()).apply();
        super.onBackPressed();  

  }

}
private void update(){

    Context context=this.getApplicationContext();
    SharedPreferences settings=context.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCES", 0);
    String value=settings.getString("value", "");
    if(value!="")A10.setText(value);
    }


}
```

You can take a demo from here